# javascript - D3.js force layout highlight without click or hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, d3.js

I am working on `d3.js` force layout. When user clicks on a node, a function is fired and in that function, a node can be expand or reduce. I would like to adapt this to work without any click. Is it possible to redraw my graph without any click ? I can successfully delete and redraw the entire graph. But this is not what I want. It take too much time and it not very efficient. I would like to do something very soft like what is done when user clicks on node. Can you please help ?
here is graph

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

      circle.node {
        cursor: pointer;
        stroke: #3182bd;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      line.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #9ecae1;
        stroke-width: 2.5px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var w = 1060,
      h = 800,
      node,
      link,
      root, 
      t;
      var COLLAPSE_LEVEL = 1;

      var force = d3.layout.force()
      .on("tick", tick)
      .size([w, h]);

      var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);
        root = {
          "name": "flare",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "analytics",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "cluster",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                    {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                    {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                    {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "graph",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
                    {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
                    {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
                    {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
                    {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "optimization",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "animate",
              "children": [
                {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
                {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
                {
                  "name": "interpolate",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
                    {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
                    {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
                    {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
                    {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
                    {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
                    {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
                    {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
                    {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
                {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
                {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
                {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
                {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
                {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
                {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
                {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
                {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "data",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "converters",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
                    {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
                    {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
                    {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
                    {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
                {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
                {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
                {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
                {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
                {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "display",
              "children": [
                {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
                {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
                {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
                {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "flex",
              "children": [
                {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "physics",
              "children": [
                {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
                {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
                {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
                {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
                {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
                {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
                {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
                {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "query",
              "children": [
                {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
                {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
                {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
                {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
                {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
                {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
                {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
                {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
                {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
                {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
                {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
                {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
                {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
                {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
                {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
                {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
                {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
                {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
                {
                  "name": "methods",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "add", "size": 593},
                    {"name": "and", "size": 330},
                    {"name": "average", "size": 287},
                    {"name": "count", "size": 277},
                    {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
                    {"name": "div", "size": 595},
                    {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
                    {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
                    {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
                    {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
                    {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
                    {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
                    {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
                    {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
                    {"name": "max", "size": 283},
                    {"name": "min", "size": 283},
                    {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
                    {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
                    {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
                    {"name": "not", "size": 386},
                    {"name": "or", "size": 323},
                    {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
                    {"name": "range", "size": 772},
                    {"name": "select", "size": 296},
                    {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
                    {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
                    {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
                    {"name": "update", "size": 307},
                    {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
                    {"name": "where", "size": 299},
                    {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
                    {"name": "_", "size": 264}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
                {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
                {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
                {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
                {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
                {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
                {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
                {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
                {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
                {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "scale",
              "children": [
                {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
                {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
                {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
                {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
                {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
                {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
                {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
                {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
                {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
                {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "util",
              "children": [
                {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
                {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
                {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
                {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
                {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
                {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
                {
                  "name": "heap",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
                    {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
                {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
                {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
                {
                  "name": "math",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
                    {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
                    {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
                {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
                {
                  "name": "palette",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
                    {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
                    {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
                    {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
                {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
                {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
                {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
                {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vis",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "axis",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
                    {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
                    {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
                    {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
                    {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "controls",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
                    {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
                    {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
                    {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
                    {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
                    {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
                    {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
                    {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
                    {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
                    {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
                    {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "data",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
                    {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
                    {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
                    {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
                    {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
                    {
                      "name": "render",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
                    {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
                    {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "events",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
                    {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
                    {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
                    {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "legend",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
                    {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
                    {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "operator",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "distortion",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "encoder",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "filter",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
                    {
                      "name": "label",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "layout",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
                    {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
                    {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
                    {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
                    {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
              ]
            }
          ]
        };





        function parseLevel(node, level) {
          node.level = level;
          if (typeof node.children !== 'undefined') {
            node.children.forEach(function(children) {
              parseLevel(children, level + 1);
            });
          }
        }

        parseLevel(root, 0);



       // console.log(JSON.stringify(root, null, 2));



      update();
      function toggleAll(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
          if (d.level < COLLAPSE_LEVEL){
            return;
          }
          toggle(d);
        }
      }
      // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
      root.children.forEach(toggleAll);


      update(root); 
      // });

      function update() {
        var nodes = flatten(root),
        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

        // Restart the force layout.
        force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .charge(-1000)
        .linkDistance(100)
        .friction(0.5)
        .start();

        // Update the links…
        link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

        // Enter any new links.
        link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        // Exit any old links.
        link.exit().remove();

        // Update the nodes…
        node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", color);

        // Enter any new nodes.
        node.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r",  "15")
        .style("fill", color)
        .on("click", mouseover)     
        .call(force.drag);

        // Exit any old nodes.
        node.exit().remove();

        t = vis.selectAll(".t-node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", color);

        // Enter any new nodes.
        t.enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("class", "t-node")
        .attr("dx", "25px")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .text(function(d){return d.name + " " + (d.level ? d.level:'')});
        // .call(force.drag);

        // Exit any old nodes.
        t.exit().remove();

      }

      function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y;});

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        t.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; }); 

      }

      // Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
      function color(d) {
        return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function mouseover(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update();
      }

      // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
      function flatten(root) {
        var nodes = [], i = 0;

        function recurse(node) {
          if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
          if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
          nodes.push(node);
        }

        recurse(root);
        return nodes;
      }
/*
      $rootScope.$on('msg', function(event, msg){
      console.log("New event accurs");
      root.name = 'root test';
      update(root); 
      update(); 
    }); */
      function toggle(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
        
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**
May by my question was not clear enough. Basically use `Angularjs` to send messages from one controller to other and what I want is to send message from other with the name of a particular node that I want to make bigger. Went this message is receive, I would like this node to be twice bigger and link around him twice bigger too.

Comment: what do you want the trigger to redraw to be?

Comment: I would like to change the size of a particular node. For example I want `util 1` to be twice bigger

Comment: I have tried to use update function, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to trigger your `mouseover` function when you "mouse over" a node. All you need for this to work is to change your `event` in your `.on(event,function)` to "mouseover".

Each node will now trigger your `mouseover` function when the user's cursor goes over the node.

Your node update section should look like this:

```
// Enter any new nodes.
node.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
.attr("r",  "10")
.style("fill", color)
.on("mouseover", mouseover)  
.call(force.drag);
```

See it in action here: [Fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/skrzym/zj3p3ar1/)

In your comments you say you are looking to change the size of a particular node. I assume you are looking to be able to do this via an event trigger as well.

In the d3-selection documentation for `.on` it explains that when `.on` is applied to a node, the triggered function is passed that node's DOM element via the `this` keyword. *(I wanted to add link to documentation but am limited to two links due to rep, I'm sure you can find it or someone else can update this with the link.)*

As an example I made two new functions `sizeUp` and `sizeDown` that I attached via the `"mouseover"` and `"mouseout"` event triggers to each node just like above using d3's `.on()` function. Each of these functions will either increase or decrease the current node's size by 10px using the `this` keyword to change the size of the correct DOM element.

Here is the node update section with `.on()` assignments for `"click"`, `"mouseover"`, and `"mouseout"`'.

```
// Enter any new nodes.
node.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
.attr("r",  "10")
.style("fill", color)
.on("mouseover", sizeUp)
.on("mouseout", sizeDown)
.on("click", mouseover)
.call(force.drag);
```

And here are the two new functions. In each, the first line retrieves the current size of the node and makes sure it is numeric. The next line updates the "r" attribute of the node by adding or subtracting 10 pixels. Note the use of `this` as a DOM element for our `d3.select()` function to retrieve. This way we can access and update the node's DOM attributes using `.attr()`.

```
function sizeUp(d){
  var currentSize = +(d3.select(this).attr("r"));
  d3.select(this).attr("r", currentSize + 10);
}

function sizeDown(d){
  var currentSize = +(d3.select(this).attr("r"));
  d3.select(this).attr("r", currentSize - 10);
}
```

See this example in action here: [Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/skrzym/xa0us730/)

Hopefully this answer has what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank for you answer.  Is there any way to trigger event without mouse ? basically I am using angularjs and would like to trigger event from an other controller. This is done with something like this   `$rootScope.$on('depSelected', function(event, msg){});`

Comment: Ah I see, I have not worked with Angularjs very much but [this article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html) might help explain some ways Angularjs and D3 can get along.

Comment: Also [this book](https://leanpub.com/d3angularjs) might be worth looking at if you really wish to learn alot more about d3 and angularjs working together. One more thing, you might want to add an `AngularJS` tag to your question so people in that community see it and can help out.